# Fixed positioned image show in one div hide in others

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images with a fixed position that all are the same, these image however should only be visible in the div with the content for it and hide behind the other div's but still scroll with the page.

I had an example where I got this inspiration from but I am unable to find it again, sorry.

Edit: Sorry forgot the code, the paragraphs are just placeholders to test the scrolling.

The images have a fixed position and should only be visible in the div they are in.

```
<div id="Over">
<div id="Job" class="grey">
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    v
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    v
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <img class="changing" id="JobImage" src="~/images/JobRapati.png" />
</div>
<div id="Web">
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <img class="changing" id="WebImage" src="~/images/webdev.png" />
</div>
<div id="Game" class="grey">
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <img class="changing" id="GameImage" src="~/images/Unity_logo.png" />
</div>
<div id="App">
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>

    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <p>Blalbalblablalbalbalblbalbalab</p>
    <img class="changing" id="AppImage" src="~/images/SummStats.png" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.changing
{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 30%; 
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you wrote so far?

Comment: a fixed position element doesn't scroll with the page - it's fixed to the viewport/window, as its name implies. try `position: absollute`instead, which fixes it in relation to its parent element (which needs to have a position setting too, preferably relative)

Comment: You can try to achieve what you want through setting parent div to position:relative and img to position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I got the question, but I don't think there is a trivial solution for what you're after. You have to hack it a bit.

I made a codepen for you. Is it something like this?

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.img {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="img"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/montik/pen/JExLRW

Comment: Yup something like this. But then with a different image appearing at the same position when it's in the container div.

Comment: maybe what you're looking for is background-attachment: fixed? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment or see the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWRRyR?editors=1100#anon-login